# Enabling/disabling components on checkcolumn action

Tags: extjs, grid

in ExtJS 5.1.0, I have a grid with checkcolumn and widgetcolumn. How to enable/disable the components of the row based on the action of checkcolumn i.e. if user checks the checkbox then the entire row components (excluding checkbox) should be disabled/readonly. If user unchecks it, the components should be enabled.

Comment: You should add some code. Anyway, the check column fires a `checkchange` event. On of the callbacks arguments is the `rowIndex` which may be used to select the widget in the same row. That's one way, not necessarily the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onWidgetAttach](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Widget-cfg-onWidgetAttach) property.

> A function that will be called when a widget is attached to a record. This may be useful for doing any post-processing.

You can add `id` property to each widget based on record data and select it later with component query (i.e. controller conttrol setup) in a grid `checkchange` event handler.